# How can I dynamically control whether to open or not open an app using AppIntents in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts, appintents

I am creating an app which uses AppIntents.Now what i want is to open the app in some cases and not open the app in some when the intent is run (via Shortucts).The `openWhenApp` variable controls whether to open the app or not.Now the issue is i can't modify this variable as it can be set only one time.
I want my app on basis of some condition to be shown on foreground and in some cases to not show.I tried the solutions suggested to similar problem but they didn't worked out.
Any help is appreciated.

```
import AppIntents

struct DefaultIntent: AppIntent {


    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "This will do something"
    
    static var description = IntentDescription("Does something")
    
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true       // opens my app when the intent is run
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        return .result()
    }
}
```